# Does free trial cancelations show in App Store Connect/ iTunes Connect?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, app-store, app-store-connect

We have an app which has subscriptions with either a monthly or yearly plan. We also offer a **7 Day Free Trial**. In App Store Connect there is a metric called "Cancelled Subscriptions".

The questions is: When a user cancels their **Free Trial** prior to being charged, does this also get triggered as "Cancelled Subscriptions"?

[image]